# Why does my FlashMapFilter display on TWO requests even though it extends OncePerRequestFilter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
public class FlashMapFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            Map<String, ?> flash = (Map<String, ?>) session.getAttribute(FlashMap.FLASH_MAP_ATTRIBUTE);
            if (flash != null) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : flash.entrySet()) {
                    Object currentValue = request.getAttribute(entry.getKey());
                    if (currentValue == null) {
                        request.setAttribute(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                    }
                }
                session.removeAttribute(FlashMap.FLASH_MAP_ATTRIBUTE);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Instead of display the Flash message once per request, this displays a message for the duration of two full requests before disappearing. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you set the attribute in the session only.

Also make sure you don't render the one that was set in the session, only the one from the request. How do you render it? Using JSP EL? Then you must explicitly use `${requestScope.flashScopeAttribute}` since `${flashScopeAttribute}` will search the sessionScope as well.

Answer (score 0):

*Once per request* means that `doFilterInternal()` won't be invoked twice in single request. For better flash scope support see [Spring 3.1 Using flash attributes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-flash-attributes).

As for your code have you tried putting a breakpoint at `session.removeAttribute`?